# TransformController rotation affects multiple axes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the THREE.TransformControls code to manipulate objects. Position and scale are independent x, y, and z but rotation on any axis (say x) will affect both the other 2 (y and z).

Is there any way to extract just the spun axis from the object.

Here's how I do it now:

```
transformControl=new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
var obj=scene.getObjectByName("myObj");                                                 
scene.add(transformControl);        
transformControl.attach(obj);               

transformControl.addEventListener("objectChange", ()=> {                                
    x=obj.position.x;    ...    
    sx=obj.scale.x;      ...    
    rx=obj.rotation.x;   ...
    }
```

Should I be pulling the rotation from a different source?

Comment: Try `q = new THREE.Quaternion(); // create once and reuse; q.copy( mesh.quaternion ); // rotate mesh...; q.angleTo( mesh.quaternion ); // in radians`.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. The numbers seemed to be relative and it was unclear how to tell which axis actually changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to cume up with a workaround:
On line 520 inTransformsControls.js I added this to capture the raw angles:

```
if (axis == 'X')        transRotX=rotationAngle;
else if (axis == 'Y')   transRotY=rotationAngle;
else if (axis == 'Z')   transRotZ=rotationAngle;
```

Not elegant, but it works.